# How can I decode the SAML response and parse the data from the decoded response ( which is XML ) using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, xml, saml

Here is say my SAML Response :

```
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
```

which gives the decoded information something similar to this ( using an online tool [here](https://samltool.io/) ) in XML format

The decoded response is something like this

```
<samlp:Response
   <saml:AttributeStatement
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <saml:Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:anyType">github|123456</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:anyType">test@gmail.com</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:anyType">test name </saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:anyType">testname@gmail.com</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="http://schemas.auth0.com/identities/default/access_token">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:anyType">3a7d0dfeffe12812c37112daa830abef570089b4</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="http://schemas.auth0.com/identities/default/provider">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:anyType">github</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="http://schemas.auth0.com/identities/default/connection">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:anyType">github</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="http://schemas.auth0.com/identities/default/isSocial">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:anyType">true</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
        </saml:AttributeStatement>
        <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2014-10-14T14:32:17.251Z">
            <saml:AuthnContext>
                <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml:AuthnContext>
        </saml:AuthnStatement>
    </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

I want to decrypt the SAML response and read the attributes from the decoded XML using Node.js

Comment: Can you share why you want to parse the data from SAML decode response?  btw did you tried `saml2js` npm package to convert it to object?

Comment: I want to parse the data from the SAML decode response so that I can use any of the attributes to fetch a document from my MongoDB collection based on that field.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution. I used `saml-encoder-decoder-js` npm package to decode your encoded token. And to get the JSON object I used `xml2json` package.

```
    const SAML = require("saml-encoder-decoder-js");
    const xmlParser = require("xml2json");
    const token = "your SAML encoded token";
    SAML.decodeSamlPost(token, function(err, xml) {
         if (err) {
            throw new Error(err);
         }
    const jsonObject = xmlParser.toJson(xml, {
            object: true,
            sanitize: true,
            trim: true
        });
    // Here you can do whatever you wanna do with the json object
    console.log(jsonObject["samlp:Response"]);
    });
```

Let me know is this solution helpful or not.

Comment: The xml2json library recommendation helped me, thanks. I'm new to SAML, but in my case it was just base64 encoding, so I didn't need saml-encoder-decoder. I just did ```Buffer.from(encodedResponse, 'base64').toString('ascii')``` (or ```toString('utf8')```) in Node.js.

Comment: @Marcus That has also worked for me but how do I extract the data from the SAML response? I can now see the XML. Do I need another library to extract this XML data? I'm currently using `passport-saml` to configure SAML on my backend

Comment: @J.Do I guess that's where you use the xml2json library as shown in Subbu's answer here, right?